# XMLWriter - setting DoNotEscapeUriAttributes and OutputMethod

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlwriter

I'm trying to create an **`XMLWriter`** with the following properties:

```
OutputMethod = XmlOutputMethod.Html
DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = true
```

**`OutputMethod` cannot be set using this:**

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

var xslCompiledTransformObj = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslCompiledTransformObj.Load(typeof(TransRep));

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { 
                                 DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = true,
                               //OutputMethod = xslCompiledTransformObj.OutputSettings.OutputMethod
                              };

var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings);
```

This sets `xslCompiledTransformObj.OutputSettings.OutputMethod` to `XmlOutputMethod.Xml` (the default)

**`DoNotEscapeUriattributes` cannot be set using this method:**

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

var xslCompiledTransformObj = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslCompiledTransformObj.Load(typeof(TransRep));

//The following line does not work:
//xslCompiledTransformObj.OutputSettings.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = true;
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings);
```

This sets `xslCompiledTransformObj.OutputSettings.OutputMethod` to `XmlOutputMethod.Html` 
and `DoNotEscapeUriAttributes` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

The XmlOutputMethod is not public, and changing it via other mechanisms (such as reflection) will not have an expected result.

[As explained by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.outputmethod.aspx):  "This setting is set by the XSLT processor and is used internally by Visual Studio."